# Changing order layers are displayed in using MMQGIS?

Tags: layers, merge, order, sorting, mmqgis

I am dealing with hundreds of different layers, all of which have one of 6 names - not by choice, that's just the way they show up when I import them.  I am trying to merge all those with the same name using MMQGIS>Combine>Merge Layers, but the layers are listed in a random order in the Merge Layers window so I cannot block off the layers I want to select using shift-arrow.  The order the layers are displayed in is different to the order in the layers panel.  I can press control & click to select different layers, but this is very time consuming and if I make a mistake all the previous selections disappear and I'm back to square one.  How can I change the order the layers are displayed in?  Click and drag would take forever.  Alphabetical order would solve my problem.

Comment: Do the shapefiles of all your layers have names you can easily seperate into 6 folders? (ie. layers with a same name, move their associated shapefiles into 1 folder)

Comment: No, the names are all identical in each folder.  I thought I would be able to merge the layers I have in the layers panel using QGIS, but it seems a solution might involve renaming and sorting them in windows explorer.  This seems very backward.